# Instantiating JavaFX property inside a JPA entity causes "Unable to load class" error

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, javafx

I have the following class in a War. It's also the only class that has any JPA annotations:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {
    protected ObjectProperty<Object> loc3 = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
}
```

When I deploy the War I get the following error:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."DevCrowd.war#prod": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."DevCrowd.war#prod": org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [pl.devcrowd.virtual.business.state.entity.BaseEntity]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:179)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:121)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:667)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:193)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [pl.devcrowd.virtual.business.state.entity.BaseEntity]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:232)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.<init>(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.<init>(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:161)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/beans/property/ObjectProperty
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:226)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty from [Module "deployment.DevCrowd.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    ... 17 more
```

but if I remove the instantiation

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {
    protected ObjectProperty<Object> loc3;
}
```

It works. This is also for IntegerProperty.

For comparison without javafx beans:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {
    Object loc3 = new Object();
}
```

works with or without initialization. Why is that?

Edit - runtime config:

[image]

Classpath entries:

[image]

Comment: Check the Java versions your build is running and the one running the server.

Comment: @Thihara As much as i can see they both use `JVM version: 1.8.0_112`

Comment: Once you make sure that that class is actually in the CLASSPATH / accessible. Your JPA provider knows how to persist an ObjectProperty does it? The ObjectProperty type that is not in the JPA spec. You have the answer in front of you. You have @AttributeConverter if you want to DEFINE how that type will be persisted ...

Comment: @NeilStockton Nowhere in the code do I try to persist ObjectProperty. If I want to I persist the Object it contains. Same for IntegerProperty. And there is no problem with ObjectProperty itself - it's the initialization that's a problem. That doesn't match what you are saying.

Comment: The exception says "cant find class", so locate the class ! And if you have a FIELD of that type then yes you do open it up to persistence (since the class CAN BE persisted).

Comment: @NeilStockton If the class was not located then I wouldn't be able to import it or compile anything with it, yet I can. As you can see I have no problem persisting if I don't initialize it. Why does initialization causes the class to not be found?

Comment: Clearly `ObjectProperty` is available at compile time, else you wouldn't have been able to compile the code. But you are getting a *runtime* error, not a compile error. So `ObjectProperty` is not on the classpath at runtime. The JVM needs to load the `ObjectProperty` class at runtime when it instantiates `BaseEntity` because `BaseEntity` has a field of type `ObjectProperty`.

Comment: So since you are using JDK 1.8.0_x on both server and client, I am just guessing that your server is not using an Oracle JDK (e.g. it has OpenJDK, for example). If that's the case, you need to include a JavaFX runtime (or at least the Java classes from it) in the server's classpath.

Comment: @James_D I added pictures that show the configuration. Wildfly uses the same oracle distribution that's used on everything else on the computer. Any ideas?

Comment: No clue about Wildfly and JBoss configuration. It would not surprise me at all though if a configuration aimed at server-side deployment omitted the JavaFX runtime. Why not just grab a build of [OpenJFX](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Main) and include it as a third-party jar, to see if it fixes the issue?

Comment: @James_D Thanks for the help about the runtime classpath. I solved it the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by the comments I read [Class Loading in WildFly](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Class+Loading+in+WildFly) and according to what's written under **Accessing JDK classes** I added this `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` to my `src\main\webapp\WEB-INF` folder:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <system export="true">
                <paths>
                    <path name="javafx/beans/property"/>
                    <path name="javafx/beans/binding"/>
                </paths>
            </system>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Both are needed even though the properties are located under `javafx.beans.property` probably because their superclasses are in `.binding`.